# Visual line mode - Moving cursor to the end of line

Tags: vim

When hitting `V` from normal mode, I'd like the cursor to move to the end.

I can manually do it with `V$h`.

I tried mapping it to `nnoremap V V$h`, but I get this:

[image]

It selects the line below and the cursor ends up in the middle.

What is going on, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Your mapping works for me.

Comment: I suggest you check which other mappings you have that might interfere with this, as it is pretty basic.

Comment: I would use `nnoremap V Vg_`

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is correct, as @ChatterOne said, check your previous mappings, for example use `:nnoremap V`